# Get Logged/Signed in Username from DefaultConnection Database VB.net 2012 ASP.NET Web Forms Application

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am a bit new to this web application stuff. When I create a new project in Visual Studios 2012 for ASP.NET Web Forms Application, it generates several predefined pages/functions. I actually want to use these functions since it seems to look like it might save me some time.

At this point I noticed how it has a Register.aspx and Login.aspx, which works fine. The **Problem is** that I have a database in Access 2007 with some tables. I want to know if it is possible to do one of the following and how:

1) keep the DefualtConnection database and query for the currently logged in username, to then use that usename to query my Access Database for the information based on that username.

2) Create my Own Register and Login using the Access Database. I wonder how do I keep track of the logged in user for this case and I also get an error when using the Create User Wizard

Please help, I need this information so that I can continue working on my final project. The Prof has no clue on how to do this, and I have been searching the web for and answer, however it seems like I may not be asking the right questions. Thanks in advance :)

*Edit
•**What I mean by logged in user:**
Picture https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22962879/Project_4_Registro_Est/Logged%20in%20user%20Project4.png

•**DefaulConnection:**

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Project_4_Registro_Est-20130131171154;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Project_4_Registro_Est-20130131171154.mdf"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

•**My Access Database**

```
myConn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\cast\Documents\test.accdb")
```

**My Solution:**
It turns out that i can get the logged in users name by calling User.Identity.Name.
So I did the following:

```
'//The following code is an example of using the Logged/signed in username to then'
'//Query other Databases based on the user name:'

    Dim myConn As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection

    Dim cmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand


    Dim sqlstring As String

    '//Connecting to My Database:'
    myConn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\cast\Documents\test.accdb")
    '//Query I wish to use to find all data based on User name:'
    sqlstring = "Select FirstName, LastName, UserType FROM users WHERE Username = '" + User.Identity.Name + "'"
    Try
        '//Start by opening the connection'
        myConn.Open()
        '//I use str for now to store the results'
        Dim str As String = ""          

        '//Set the command by adding the SQL string and Connection:'
        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlstring, myConn)
        '//Create variable which contains results from Executed command:'
        Dim oledbReader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        '//Keep reading each row that contains the Queried Results:'
        While oledbReader.Read
            '//Store result to str. each item is a Column in the order I Queried'
            str = str + (oledbReader.Item(0) & " " & oledbReader.Item(1) & " (" & oledbReader.Item(2)).ToString() & ")" + "\n"
        End While

        '//Show results on page's Label1:'
        Label1.Text = str

        '//Close everything'
        oledbReader.Close()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        '//show error message if could not connect'
        MsgBox("Can not open connection! X_X")
    End Try
```

Comment: Please post a connection string and some notes on what you mean by logged in user.

Comment: I added more information...

Comment: That is not MS Access, that is SQL Server, Local DB, AFAICT.

Comment: What do you mean by "I also get an ever "?

Comment: @Remou
Yes, I know it is not an Access DB. Visual Studios 2012 now uses that local database as a default database. I did not want to spend more time creating the database because I had no clue as to how to do that.

So, what I wanted from that local DB is the logged/signed in usesname, so that I can leave the default stuff as is since everything is working fine. however I want to use My access server to created the rest of the database tables and simply query from there.

Comment: @AnnL.
Sorry for the typo. i have no clue how I made that mistake. What i wanted to say was "I also get an error"

Answer (score 0):

This should be using SimpleMembership.  So ask `WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CurrentUserName`.  Also `WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated` would be good to look at.